# laravel5 create custom disk for uploading photo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.6 and i wanted to create my custom disk for uploading images

and i received this error

> InvalidArgumentException Driver [] is not supported.

this is how i save file in controller

```
    $cover = $request->file('cover_image');
    $extension = $cover->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::disk('test')->put($cover->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($cover));
```

this is my `config/filesystems.php`

```
   'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'test' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/asghar'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error occurred because my configuration was cached.
probably I accidentally used `config:cache` or sth similar.

the issue resolved by clearing the config cache using this command

```
php artisan config:clear
```